# Prove that $i\not\in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ for algebraic $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, WITHOUT using that $i \not\in \mathbb R$ (or referencing $\mathbb R$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Using real/complex numbers, it's easy to see that e.g. [Is the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[m]{n})/\mathbb{Q}$ not Normal for $m > 1$ and $n$ square free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711605). Another example is [Why is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) $ is not normal over $\mathbb{Q}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558369). Even in the case of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ I have seen the proof that this is not normal because $(x^3-2) = (x-\sqrt[3]2) (x^2+x\sqrt[3]2 + \sqrt[3]4)$, and the quadratic has no real roots (by looking at the discriminant in the quadratic formula). But these proofs all rely on properties of $\mathbb R$, chief among them being the fact that $x\in \mathbb R \implies x^2 \geq 0$ (so order properties of $\mathbb R$). Using this strategy, given algebraic $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$ s.t. the minimal polynomial $m_\alpha$ has a real root, I can take $\alpha'$ to be that real root, construct the field extension $\mathbb Q(\alpha') \subseteq \mathbb R$ (which obviously does not contain $i\in \mathbb C$), and hence $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ (the abstract algebraic object) can not contain $i$ (i.e. any root of $x^2+1$) because $\mathbb Q(\alpha) \simeq \mathbb Q(\alpha')$ as fields and $\mathbb Q(\alpha')$ has no roots of $x^2+1 \in \mathbb Q[x]$.

Of course, in the case of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ one can use the result that if $[F(\alpha):F]$ and $[F(\beta):F]$ are relatively prime, then $[F(\alpha,\beta):F]=[F(\alpha):F]\cdot[F(\beta):F]$ to show that $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,i):\mathbb Q] = 6$ and hence $i \not\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$, because $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2):\mathbb Q] = 3$, the degree of the irreducible (by Eisenstein) polynomial $x^3-2$ with $\sqrt[3]2$ as a root. But one can not even use this strategy to show $i \not\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$.

---

**My question:** there probably isn't a general way to prove the titular result without referring to $\mathbb R$, but e.g. for the "simple rooty field extensions" in the first paragraph, is it possible? The way I phrased the question in the title is a admitedlly bit too broad, since in the very statement of the question I'm forced to use $\mathbb R$. But for "simple rooty extensions", the presence of the real line should not be as crucial, right?

Comment: $i \not \in \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ because (evidently, enumerating the elements of absolute value $< 2$) $\sqrt2\not \in \Bbb{Z}[i]$. Or because $\Bbb{Q}(i,\sqrt2)=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$ which has degree $4$ because $(x+1)^4+1$ is Eisenstein at $2$. Or because $2$ is a square $\bmod 7$ but $-1$ isn't a square $\bmod 7$. Plenty of approaches, that depend on the field. There is also a general naive algorithm to check if $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$, enumerating the elements of $\frac1{D}\Bbb{Z}[\alpha],D=Disc(\Bbb{Z}[\alpha])$ of Minkowski norm $\le 1$.

Comment: Artin and Schreier developed the theory of real closed field which does away with the need for analytic properties of $\mathbb {R}, \mathbb{C} $ and instead one works with the field $\overline {\mathbb{Q}} $ of algebraic numbers and its real closed subfield (which turns out to be the field of real algebraic numbers).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How do you show that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is ordered?

Comment: @reuns : I am no expert here, but I think we can have two orderings in this field depending upon whether we want to have square root of $2$ as positive or negative.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes but to show that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ has one ordering I would  define the order from a sequence $s_n$ of rationals converging to $\sqrt2$ (in $\Bbb{R}$) so that $a\sqrt2+ b >0$ iff $a s_n+b>0$ for every $n$ large enough. This is not very different to embedding into $\Bbb{R}$, so that's why I'm asking if you have a less real solution.

Comment: @reuns: we can consider directly numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ with $a, b$ rational. If both $a, b$ are of same sign then the number is of same sign as that of either of $a, b$. If they are of opposite signs then we can consider $a>0,b<0$ and then $a+b\sqrt{2}=(a^2-2b^2)/(a-b\sqrt{2}) $ is positive or negative according as the numerator $a^2-2b^2$. Same way we can deal with $a<0,b>0$. The case when $ab=0$ is simpler.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok, but how do you prove that it works? I mean it fails with $i$ instead of $\sqrt2$. Also probably quite specific to quadratic fields as for degree $n$ fields the coefficients of $N(a)/a$ will have mixed signs .

Comment: @reuns : well, for any ordered field $F$ adjoining square roots of positive elements of $F$ leads to a formally real field (and it can be ordered). This is described in Jacobson's *Lectures in Abstract Algebra* Vol 3, last chapter on Artin-Schreier Theory. I think the adjoining of square root of positive elements behaves in a significantly different way compared to adjoining square roots of negative elements.

Comment: @reuns: maybe you can ask this as a separate question and I hope some experts in this area can elaborate more.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I agree with you now that for square roots it is not hard, it is the opposite you should write an answer showing that for $\sqrt2$ the order can be done relatively formally without really thinking to $\Bbb{R}$ (which implies that $i\not \in \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ as a square can't be negative in an ordered field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the currently accepted answer has an error: it is claimed that the
automorphism sending $\sqrt[m]{n}$ to $\zeta_m \sqrt[m]{n}$ **is easily
seen to have order $m$** without further argument, whereas that is only
clear if that automorphism fixes $\zeta_m$. But it need not fix $\zeta_m$  without further
argument. For example, as noted in another answer, the field
$\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[6]{-3})$ is Galois of degree six with Galois group
$S_3$ which has no elements of order $6$, and the automorphism sending $\sqrt[6]{-3}$ to $\sqrt[6]{-3} \cdot \zeta_6$ actually has order $2$.

We prove the following stronger statement. Let $m > 0$ and
let $n$ be an integer so that $x^m - n$ is irreducible. Suppose
that $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ with $\alpha = \sqrt[m]{n}$ is the splitting
field of $x^m - n$. Then either:

1. $m = 1$ or $m = 2$,
2. $m = 6$ and $n = - 3 a^2$ for some integer $a$ where $n$ is not a cube.
3. $m = 4$ and $n = - a^2$ for some integer $a$.

Conversely, in these cases, $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ is the splitting field.

Note that $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ being the splitting field of $x^m -n$
is equivalent to $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ being Galois over $\mathbf{Q}$.

First some reductions. If $m > 1$ is odd, then $L = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$
can never be Galois. This is because $L$ must contain $K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$,
which has degree $\varphi(m)$ which is even for $m > 2$.
(You seem to be happy to accept that the degree of $K$ is $\varphi(m)$, although this is not
so easy. The easiest proof to me that the degree is even when $m > 2$ is to use complex conjugation! The only facts about the degree of $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$ we use is that it is even for $m > 2$ and bigger than $2$ unless $m = 1,2,3,4,6$)

Second, for any $m$ which is not a power of $2$, the extension $L = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[m]{n})$
can never be Galois *and* abelian. If it is abelian,
then any subfield is also Galois. But now taking $p > 2$
to be the largest power of $p$ dividing $m$, the extension $L$ contains $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[p]{n})$,
which we previously have seen is never Galois. (Subfields of abelian Galois fields are always Galois.)

The result is trivially true for $m=1$ and $m = 2$.  If $m = 6$,
then $n$ is neither a cube nor a square since otherwise $x^6 - n$ is not irreducible.
But if $n$ is not a square then the splitting field of $x^6 - n$ contains
$(\sqrt[6]{n})^3 = \sqrt{n}$, but also contains $\zeta_6$ and hence $\sqrt{-3}$.
If these two fields are  the same,  then $n = - 3 a^2$ for some integer $a$.
If $n$ is not of this form, however, then the splitting field contains two
distinct quadratic fields, and hence contains their compositum which has degree $4$.
But then the degree $6$ extension given by adjoining a single root
cannot contain the degree $4$ extension and hence is not Galois.

If $n = -3 a^2$, then $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[6]{n})$ contains
$(\sqrt[6]{n})^3 = \sqrt{-3 a^2}$ and thus contains $\sqrt{-3}$
and $\zeta_6$, and hence these extensions are Galois.

If $m = 4$, then $n$ is not a square since otherwise $x^4 - n$ is not irreducible. But if $n$ is not a square then
the splitting field of $x^4 - n$ contains $(\sqrt[4]{n})^2 = \sqrt{n}$, but also contains $\zeta_4$ and hence $\sqrt{-1}$.
If these two fields are the same, then $n = - a^2$ for some integer $a$. If $n = a^2$ then, as above,
the field $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[4]{n})$ contains $\sqrt{-a^2}$ and thus $\sqrt{-1}$ and is hence Galois.
If not, then $K$ must contain the compositum of $\sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{-1}$. But unlike the case $m = 6$ where $4$ did not divide $6$, in this case we can only deduce that there is an equality

$$\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[4]{n}) = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{n}).$$

Since the Galois group has order $4$ and acts transitively on the roots of $x^4 - n$, any non-trivial element
must act non-trivially on every root. (Otherwise there is not enough elements to sent that root to every other root.) By looking at the Galois group of the right hand side, we see that there must be an order $2$ element $\sigma$ which fixes $\sqrt{n}$ but not $i = \sqrt{-1}$.
If $\sigma \sqrt[4]{n} = \pm i \sqrt[4]{n}$, then $\sigma \sqrt{n} = - \sqrt{n}$ contradicting the assumption that $\sigma$
fixes $\sqrt{n}$. Hence $\sigma \sqrt[4]{n} = - \sqrt[4]{n}$ (since it cannot fix any root) and $\sigma i \sqrt[4]{n} = - i \sqrt[4]{n}$.
But then, taking the ratio, we find that

$$\sigma i = \frac{\sigma i \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sigma \sqrt[4]{n}} =  \frac{- i \sqrt[4]{n}}{-\sqrt[4]{n}}  = i,$$

a contradiction. This completes the case of $m = 4$.

We now proceed by induction.
Having considered the cases $m=1$, $m = 2$, $m=3$ ($m$ odd), $m = 4$, and $m = 6$, we may assume that $\varphi(m) > 2$.

Suppose that $x^m - n$ is irreducible. Let $\alpha = \sqrt[m]{n}$,
and let $\zeta = \zeta_m$ be a primitive $m$th root of unity.
Let $L = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$. The roots of $x^m - n$ are of the
form $\alpha \zeta^i$ for some $i = 0,1,\ldots,m-1$.
Assume that $L$ is Galois. Then $L$ contains $\zeta$ and
hence the field $K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$. Note that $[K:\mathbf{Q}] = \varphi(m)$,
so $m = r s$ for some integer $r = [L:K]$ and $s = \varphi(m)$.

Let $G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbf{Q})$ and let $H = \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ which
has order $r$. Any element of $H$ fixes $\zeta$ by definition and  sends $\alpha$
to $\alpha \zeta^k$ for some $k$. But since $\sigma$ fixes $\zeta$,
it then acts on all the roots of $x^m - n$ as multiplication by $\zeta^k$. It follows that $H$
is cyclic of order $d$ where  $d$ is the smallest integer such
that $dk \equiv 0 \bmod m$. Since $|H| = r$, we have $r = d$.

We see that $\alpha^r = (\sqrt[m]{n})^r = (\sqrt[rs]{n})^r = \sqrt[s]{n}$ is fixed by $H$ and
thus $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[s]{n}) \subseteq L^{H} = K$. But we have

$$r \ge [\mathbf{Q}(\alpha):\mathbf{Q}(\alpha^r)] = [L:K] \cdot [K:\mathbf{Q}(\alpha^r)] = r  \cdot [K:\mathbf{Q}(\alpha^r)],$$

and hence $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[s]{n}) = K$. In particular, $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[s]{n})$
is Galois of degree $s = \varphi(m)$ and equal to $K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$.
Moreover,  $\sqrt[s]{n}$ is a root of $x^s - n$, which is irreducible because
$\sqrt[s]{n}$ has degree $s$. So $\sqrt[s]{n}$  generates a Galois
extension $K$ which must therefore be the splitting field of this polynomial.
In addition, this splitting field $K$  is abelian. By our preliminary remarks,
this is a contradiction unless $s$ is a power of $2$. But by induction we obtain
a contradiction unless $s \le 2$, or unless $\varphi(m) \le 2$.
But this implies that $m=1,2,3,4,6$, cases which we have already considered.

Comment: Oh dear it seems my question has garnered a lot of interest beyond my levels of expertise! I will have to take a while to think about all these answers and comments. Thank you for your contribution; do you mind sharing how you came across this question? It’s not common that a question gets any views, much less any answers days after it’s asked.

Answer (score 3):

This is based on my comments to the question.

There is an algebraic way to get something similar to $\mathbb {R} $ and Artin and Schreier developed this whole concept of formally real and real closed fields. Let us first define an *ordered field* as a pair $F, P$ where $F$ is a field and $ P\subseteq F$ such that

- $0\notin P$
- if $a\in F$ then either $a\in P$ or $a=0$ or $-a\in P$
- $P$ is closed under addition and multiplication operations of $F$.

One can observe that any non-zero square must lie in $P$ and thus $1\in P$ and thus an ordered field is necessarily of characteristic $0$. Further if $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\in F$ then $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=0\implies a_i=0 \text{ for each }i $$ This property is used to develop the idea of a formally real field.

A field $F$ is said to be *formally real* if the only relations of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=0$ in $F$ are those for which $a_i=0$. Note again that a formally real field must be of characteristic $0$. And then we can say that every ordered field is formally real.

It is a bit surprising that the converse is also true that *every formally real field can be ordered*. The order may not necessarily be unique (as it is for $\mathbb{Q} $). For example $\mathbb{ Q} (\sqrt{2})$ is formally real and it has two distinct orderings.

It can also be noted that definition of a formally real field is equivalent to the condition that *$-1$ can not be expressed as a sum of squares in such a field*. And thus we can't have $i$ (square root of $-1$) in any formally real field.

The theory of formally real fields becomes interesting when we try to find out a maximal formally real field in the following sense. A formally real field $F$ is said to be *real closed* if $F$ has no proper algebraic extension which is formally real.

Next we can we can start with any formally real field $F$ and generate its algebraic closure $\overline{F} $ via algebraic processes. And then we can consider the collection $\mathcal{C} $ of fields $K$ given by $$\mathcal{C} =\{K\mid F\subseteq K\subseteq \overline {F}, K \text{ is formally real} \} $$ and using Zorn's lemma find a maximal element $F_{rc} $ of $\mathcal{C} $. It can be proved that $F_{rc} $ is a real closed field and is essentially unique and has a unique ordering. The field $F_{rc} $ is called the *real closure* of $F$ (I have used the subscript "rc" to mean real closure). The same process can be applied for an ordered field $F$ (as it is also formally real).

Applying the above process to $\mathbb{Q} $ gives us the field $\mathbb {Q} _{rc} $ and its elements are called *real algebraic numbers*. Real closed fields have many properties which are similar to that of $\mathbb {R} $.

If $F$ is a real closed field then

- $F$ is ordered with the squares of non-zero elements being considered positive and thus every positive member of $F$ has a square root in $F$.
- if $f(x) \in F[x] $ is of odd degree then $f(x) $ has a root in $F$.
- because of the above two properties $F(i) $ is an algebraically closed field.
- polynomials in $F[x] $ satisfy intermediate value theorem, Rolle's theorem, mean value theorem and extreme value theorem.

The proofs of above properties are fully algebraic and really very interesting. For details one may have a look at last chapter on Artin-Schreier Theory in Jacobson's *Lectures in Abstract Algebra*, Vol. 3.

The development of these ideas allows us to handle the algebraic numbers (both real and complex) without actually using any analysis. Dealing with polynomials of the form $x^n-a\in \mathbb {Q} [x] $ is then straightforward. If $n$ is odd then this polynomial has only one root in $\mathbb {Q} _{rc} $ and rest of the roots lie in $\overline {\mathbb{Q}} $. If $n$ is even then we have either $0$ or $2$ roots in $\mathbb {Q} _{rc} $ depending on $a<0$ or $a\geq 0$ and rest of the roots lie in $\overline {\mathbb {Q}} $.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague because it's not entirely clear what the rules are when you say you can "not use $\mathbf{R}$". One pretty strict way to formulate this is to say that you cannot use any inequalities. But one remark is that if you assume $x^m - n$ is irreducible (say by assuming that $n$ has at least one prime divisor and is squarefree) and you want to prove that this is not normal when $m > 2$ you will *have* to assume that $n > 0$ rather than $n < 0$ since it is not true otherwise. For example, $x^6 + 3$ is irreducible and yet the splitting field is given by taking any root of this polynomial. So in this strict sense you have to invoke the fact that $n > 0$ and implicitly use $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: I think inequalities and order properties for elements of $\mathbb Q$ are fine, since you can define those just from the construction of $\mathbb Q$ from $\mathbb Z$, which is in turn constructed from $\mathbb N$/the Peano axiom or something. I guess using order properties of $\mathbb Q$ one can show that $i \not\in \mathbb Q$... and maybe we can endow $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ with an order, without the analytic machinery of $\mathbb R$? The main thing I want to avoid is mention of $\mathbb R$ at all, since to even construct $\mathbb R$ requires substantial analytic tools.

Answer (score 0):

Ring extension equals field extension: $\Bbb Q[\alpha] = \Bbb Q(\alpha)$.

So if this extension has degree $n$, then each element of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ has the form

$a_{n-1} \alpha^{n-1} + \ldots a_1\alpha + a_0$ with all $a_i\in\Bbb Q$.

This expression lies in $\Bbb R$ by hypothesis

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but maybe that is not what OP wants since they are saying "without using the fact that $i\notin \Bbb R$"?

Comment: @Didier yes... perhaps I should make the "without" more eye-catching, but uppercase seems a bit distasteful